# Is there a better way to conditionally check out either main or a specific branch in a Github action?

Tags: git, github-actions

I've got this working but I'm not happy with it.
[Action Definition](https://github.com/oldgaffers/boatregister/blob/main/.github/workflows/crud.yml)

The simple case is a new change to a specific file which should create a branch, commit the change to the branch and create a pull request for the change.

But if the branch + PR already exist, I want to check out that branch, and add the change as an additional commit to the branch.

What I wanted to do was checkout the whole repo, including branches and then test locally if the branch exists and create and push it if it doesn't.

What I've ended up with is an initial checkout of main which gets the authorisation to look remotely for the branch and then checkout the branch if it does exist.

Any ideas how I can avoid the double checkout?

Comment: When you fetched all the remote branches can't you just use ```git checkout my-branch``` and then ```git switch -c my-branch```. The checkout will look for a remote branch and use it if it exists and the switch makes sure that you create the branch and switch to it if you didn't check it out from the remote. (I'm not sure that I completely understood the problem, but maybe this helps.)

Comment: @grottenolm - you are understanding the question. That's pretty much what I tried, but actions/checkout@v3 doesn't seem to get the pr branch, even with fetch-depth: 0.

Comment: That is, if you use `actions/checkout` with `fetch-depth: 0` and then try to checkout the PR branch it doesn't work? That would be strange, I also tested this once and everything worked so far.
Have you tried to add a `git fetch -a` after the `actions/checkout` or to look via `git branch -a -v` which branches are fetched?

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a go. As it's working, it's not at the top of the list so might not be soon, but the suggestions are much appreciated.